# VBnet return a list(of class) where field is between 2 values

Tags: vb.net

I'm kind of new to this type of programming.
I'm working on a small program that will read from a text file: sort the data and gives me the last 10 entries within the criteria (Data, specific machine and program used).
Right now I got it sorted pretty good by using a List(of class).

Posting all the code would give you half a page to read so this is a snippet, let me know if you need more (parts are in dutch):

```
            '-------------------- Sorteren via Machine/programma --------------------
            If TreeView1.SelectedNode.FullPath.Contains("/") Then
                SortedFilterMachine = sorted.Where(Function(y) SelectedMachineParent.Contains(y.DataMachine)).ToList
                SortedFilterProgram = SortedFilterMachine.Where(Function(y) SelectedMachineChild.Contains(y.DataProg)).ToList
                SortedListMachineProg = SortedFilterProgram
            Else
                SortedFilterMachine = sorted.Where(Function(y) SelectedMachineParent.Contains(y.DataMachine)).ToList
                SortedListMachineProg = SortedFilterMachine
            End If

            '------------------- Sorteren via geselecteerde datum ------------------
```

How I do my parsing & filling in the List(of class):

```
    Dim sr As New StringReader(TextUpload)
    Dim DataList = New List(Of DataEntry)()
    Dim srline As String
    Dim line = New List(Of String)

    Do While sr.Peek() >= 0
        Dim d = New DataEntry()
        srline = sr.ReadLine
        line.Add(srline)
        'MsgBox(srline)
        Data = srline.Split(New String() {";"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            If Data.Length < 9 Then
                With d
                    .DataMachine = (Data(0).Split("]", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Last)
                    .DataProg = (Data(1).Split("]", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Last)
                    .DataDate = Mid((Data(2).Split("_", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).First), 7) '//DataDate splitsen In enkel numerieke waardes
                    '.DataDate = Data(2)
                    .DataType = (Data(3).Split("]", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Last)
                    .DataID = (Data(4).Split("]", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Last)
                    .DataOldValue1 = (Data(5).Split("]", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Last)
                    .DataNewValue1 = (Data(6).Split("]", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Last)
                End With
            Else
                If Data.Length > 8 Then
                    With d
                        .DataMachine = (Data(0).Split("]", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Last)
                        .DataProg = (Data(1).Split("]", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Last)
                        .DataDate = Mid((Data(2).Split("_", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).First), 7)
                        .DataType = (Data(3).Split("]", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Last)
                        .DataID = (Data(4).Split("]", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Last)
                        .DataOldValue1 = (Data(5).Split("]", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Last)
                        .DataNewValue1 = (Data(6).Split("]", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Last)
                        .DataOldValue2 = (Data(7).Split("]", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Last)
                        .DataNewValue2 = (Data(8).Split("]", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Last)
                    End With

Public Class DataEntry
    Public DataMachine As String
    Public DataProg As Integer
    Public DataDate As Integer
    Public DataType As String
    Public DataID As Integer
    Public DataOldValue1 As String
    Public DataNewValue1 As String
    Public DataOldValue2 As String
    Public DataNewValue2 As String
End Class
```

Like above I want it to return my List(of class) but without the entries that are not within the selected scope.

I take the date from 2 "DateTimePicker". Inside the list(of class) I assigned the Integer format to numeric data from the file.

But I cannot find the right instruction for it, I was looking through the posibilities but assume I cannot do it like this:

```
SortedListResult = SortedListMachineProg.Where(Function(x) DateEnd.Max(x.DataDate)).ToList
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT:
Addes more of my code,
Changed some unclearities,
Example of file text:

```
[MACHINE]LBL;[PROG]2;[DATE]20210422_151334;[TYPE]BOOL;[ID]13;[OLD_VALUE]FALSE;[NEW_VALUE]TRUE;
[MACHINE]LBL;[PROG]5;[DATE]20210422_151334;[TYPE]INT;[ID]16;[OLD_VALUE]1;[NEW_VALUE]5;
[MACHINE]LBL;[PROG]4;[DATE]20210422_151335;[TYPE]TRIGGER;[ID]6;[OLD_VALUE_1]45;[NEW_VALUE_1]0;[OLD_VALUE_2]0;[NEW_VALUE_2]0;[OLD_VALUE_3]0;[NEW_VALUE_2]0;
```

Comment: "I filled the data fom the text file into integer type": why? Is it stored as an integer in your text file or are you specifically casting a date to an integer?

Comment: No, the text is all string, an example of one line: `[MACHINE]LBL;[PROG]5;[DATE]20210422_151334;[TYPE]INT;[ID]16;[OLD_VALUE]1;[NEW_VALUE]5;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the datatype of `DataDate` to `DateTime`. I find it is easiest to deal with dates when they are real dates.

Then you can use the date values directly from the DateTimePickers to filter the list using Linq.

```
Public Class DataEntry
    Public DataMachine As String
    Public DataProg As Integer
    Public DataDate As DateTime
    Public DataType As String
    Public DataID As Integer
    Public DataOldValue1 As String
    Public DataNewValue1 As String
    Public DataOldValue2 As String
    Public DataNewValue2 As String
End Class

Private lstMachineData As New List(Of DataEntry)

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\maryo\Desktop\Code\Machine Data.txt")
    For Each line In lines
        Dim Data = line.Split({";"c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        Dim d As New DataEntry
        With d
            .DataMachine = Data(0).Split({"]"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Last
            .DataProg = CInt(Data(1).Split({"]"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Last)
            .DataDate = Date.ParseExact(Data(2).Split({"]"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Last, "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) '//DataDate splitsen In enkel numerieke waardes
            .DataType = Data(3).Split({"]"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Last
            .DataID = CInt(Data(4).Split({"]"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Last)
            .DataOldValue1 = Data(5).Split({"]"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Last
            .DataNewValue1 = (Data(6).Split({"]"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Last)
        End With
        If Data.Length > 8 Then
            With d
                .DataOldValue2 = (Data(7).Split({"]"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Last)
                .DataNewValue2 = (Data(8).Split({"]"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Last)
            End With
        End If
        lstMachineData.Add(d)
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Dim d1 As Date = DateTimePicker1.Value 'Start date
    Dim d2 As Date = DateTimePicker2.Value 'End Date
    Dim filteredList = (From data As DataEntry In lstMachineData
                        Select data Where data.DataDate >= d1 And data.DataDate <= d2).ToList
    For Each d As DataEntry In filteredList
        Debug.Print(d.DataDate.ToString)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a very interesting piece of code for me, I tried to copy paste it my file to look at the strings it will generate.
The "CultureInfo.InvariantCulture" asks to be defined, could it that you somehow forgot to paste this part?
Thank you for your effort.

Comment: EDIT: I found that you have to import System.Globalization for this to work (cannot edit a comment older than 5minutes)

Comment: do you, per chance, know how to fix publishing in VS2019? It keeps loading in an infinite loop when I right click the project and click publish..

Comment: @KevinVR That would be a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a wrapper class around the row that implements the parsing logic of a single row and converts the datetime values into .NET datetime values etc.

```
Public Class InputLine

    Public Sub New(line As String)
        'Implement parsing logic here and assign properties
        OriginalLine = line
    End Sub

    Public Property Data As String

    Public Property Machine As String

    Public Property Program As String

    Public Property OriginalLine As String

End Class
```

Then you can simply do all the filtering and sorting with Linq:

```
Dim lines As String() = File.ReadAllLines("C:\Temp\Input.dat")
Dim result As String() = (From e In lines Let r = New InputLine(e) Where r.Program = "Notepad" Order By r.Data Descending Take 10 Order By r.Data Ascending Select r.OriginalLine).ToArray()
Return result
```

Comment: Than you for your response. But I cannot quite follow what you mean.
As I see it Parsing means breaking down a string into segments with the size of your liking, is this correct?
Also: why do you do "OriginalLine = line"?
I'll try to  merge your code with what I have written and see if I stumble unto conflicts.

Comment: I begin to see what you are trying to do. You are using the same method as the "List(of Class)" I made. With the exception that you start from the whole file and parse it inside the Public class whereas I parsed it (and assigned the data to the defined public properties) outside the public class.
Am I correct in assuming your code wille give me a List(of InputLine) with Data, machine, program & each line?

Comment: If you don't call `.OriginalLine` then yes, otherwise it returns the exact strings of the lines that matched the filter.

Comment: Christoph, I get 2 errors:
`.. Let r = New InputLine(e) where r.Program = ...` the "e" gives "Too many arguments to Public Sub New()
Could this be because r.Data is called upon twice? `..r.Data Descending Take 10 Order By r.Data Ascending..` ?
Also: `Return result` gives "'return' statement in a sub or a set cannot return a value": but it needs to be in a sub because i want it to be triggered by a button click?

Comment: You didn't implement the constructor of `InputLine` like I did. It needs 1 argument, the line. Just compy my example, it compiles and works and then adapt it to your needs. The twice is to get the last 10 elements sorted in ascending order.